# Changing view layout params in fragment not working (API 16 and 17)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I created a very simple fragment with one ImageView in it.
In my fragment, I just want to change the height of the imageView.

Here is the Java code:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (getView() != null) {
        final ImageView imageViewTest = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.image_test);
        imageViewTest.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {
                imageViewTest.getLayoutParams().height = 750;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

And here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#FF1234"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how I add my fragment in my activity:

```
// my_layout is FrameLayout:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.my_layout, new TestFragment())
    .commit();
```

But I have a very weird and annoying problem: if I add my fragment that way in the onCreate() of my activity, my imageView is resized. But if I add my fragment after a certain period of time (or in a button click for example), my imageView is not resized, *even if the line of code that resizes my imageView is executed!*

**IMPORTANT:** I only have this problem in older versions of Android (I tested API 16 and 17). I don't have this problem in API 24 for example.

Does anybody know why? Is there any workaround ? Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:** the imageView is resized when I resize it in the onActivityCreated() instead of the onLayoutChange()...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = imageViewTest.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 750;
imageViewTest.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Otherwise the View is not redraw that why the size doesn't change.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve, when do you want to change the ImageView size? Why not setting the size directly in the xml or programmatically in onCreateView?

Comment: This example was for the sake of simplicity. I actually want to get the size and position of some views in my fragment and resize my imageView according to it. That's why I use `onLayoutChange()`